# Equality of Expectations of Mixture Distributions

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Let N be a Poisson r.v. with parameter $\lambda$. Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ and $X_0,X_1,...$ be independent, identically distributed, nonnegative integer valued r.v. with finite mean. Show that for any function g (such that the expectations exist) we have

$E[Yg(Y)]=\lambda E[X_0g(Y+X_0)]$.

Assuming $X_i$'s and N are independent, I obtained

$E[Yg(Y)|N=n]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_ig(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)]$

and then

$E[Yg(Y)]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\left(\sum_{i=1}^kE\left[X_ig\left(\sum_{j=1}^kX_j\right)\right]\right)$

I tried to interchange two summations but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Next, one recognizes that each very last sum (on $i$) is $$k E(X_kg(X_1+\cdots+X_k))=kE(X_0g(X_1+\cdots+X_{k-1}+X_0))$$ and one computes that the prefactor of each term (in the sum on $k$) is then $$\lambda e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k-1}/(k-1)!=\lambda P(N=k-1).$$ Can you end this?

Comment: Yes. I've just ended it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Post what you did as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[image: solution]

I'm so sorry that I don't have time to type my answer here, now. Here's the image of my solution!